# AVR usart communcation with arduino

Tags: serial-port, arduino, avr

I am trying to setup up a basic serial communcation link between an [ATMEGA8515](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2512.pdf) and an Arduino Uno. I am Putty connection to the correct com port I can see the Arudino print "got:got:" in burst of two going with the delay. So the problem is that the Arduino is recognizing that something is being transmitted but not getting any characters.

I've been trying to use the transmit code on page 143 of the [datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/images/doc2512.pdf) in my main loop:

```
int main(void)
{
    //Baud is 9600
    USART_Init(USART_BAUDRATE); 
    //init interrupt
    sei();
    
    DDRA |= _BV(DDA6); 
    while(1)
    {
        USART_Transmit("a\n");
        _delay_ms(5000);
    }
}
```

And trying to recieve the serial using this code taken from [here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Learning/Tutorial01):

```
char val; // variable to receive data from the serial port
void setup() {
  Serial.begin(9600);       // start serial communication at 9600bps
}
void loop() {
  if( Serial.available() )       // if data is available to read
  {
    val = Serial.read();         // read it and store it in 'val'
    Serial.print("got:"+val);
  }
  
  delay(100);                    // wait 100ms for next reading
}
```

This results in "got:" being printed twice every 5 seconds:
[image]

I hooked up an LED to the TX line of the AVR and can see when its tranmitting. The TX line of the AVR is hooked into the RX line of the arduino and the same fasion for AVR RX.

Any ideas why I can't see the char that i'm trying to transmit?

One odd thing is that the RX light never blinks on the Arduino making it seem that its not getting anything but the TX always blinks as its printing to the com port.

EDIT:
This is the code i'm using for transmit:

```
void USART_Transmit( unsigned char data )
{
/* Wait for empty transmit buffer */
while ( !( UCSRA & (1<<UDRE)) )
;
/* Put data into buffer, sends the data */
UDR = data;
}
```

and have changed my main code to `USART_Transmit("a");`
I also tried  `Serial.print(val, HEX);` on the arduino which prints 0s.

Comment: Are you feeding the TTL serial output of the ATmega straight into the RS232 port on the Arduino? The logic levels are inverted between TTL and RS232.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was the Baud rate was wrong.

After measuring it on an oscilloscope I found that it was wrong. I used the baud rate prescaler:

```
#define BAUD_PRESCALE ( (F_CPU / (USART_BAUDRATE * 16UL)) - 1 )
```

Which gave me garbage chars but a step in the right direction. I then knocked down the baud to 2400 and got the char and strings that I wanted printed to putty.

Answer (score 2):

It's not a good practice to have a delay() in your loop, much less if you're expecting to receive serial data.

For your arduino code, instead of relying `Serial.available()` to be run just after you receive the serial data, you should use `serialEvent()` function.

You just have to implement this function

```
void serialEvent() {
    //write your code here
}
```

Keep in mind that this function will be called whenever serial data arrives thru the corresponding serial port.

For arduino mega, as there are more than one serial port you can also use `serialEvent1()`, `serialEvent2()`, `serialEvent3()`.

it is also important to know that currently these functions are not compatible with the Esplora, Leonardo, or Micro.

You can read more about this in the [arduino reference](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/SerialEvent)

Here's an [example](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SerialEvent)

Answer (score 0):

[This page](http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/StringAdditionOperator) has some warnings about using the string `+` operator. The examples that don't work correctly look something like yours.

Try

```
String got = "got:";
Strint toPrint = got + val;
Serial.print(toPrint);
```

Comment: If I just print the `val` with no concatenation it just prints blank spaces.

Comment: @Nick Spaces are better than no spaces. The datasheet function you mention only works for char or int. You must have done something else to have it allow a string input. Maybe the problem is there. Include your version in the question.

Comment: @Nick I don't see why that even compiles. You are sending a string where the function expects a char. If anything, you should be sending 'a' (single quotes). I suspect that the function is getting the address of the string (whatever that is) instead of the first character. It is likely to be a non-printing character.

Answer (score 0):

Try printing `val` as a hex or decimal value. You may be trying to print a non-printable character.

```
Serial.print(val, HEX);
Serial.print(val, DEC);
```

Comment: This prints 0 for both which I think is a step in the right direction for figuring out the problem. Seems like the transmit maybe doing something wrong.